# Create new Column in Dataframe from every nth element in a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to construct a new column in a data frame that is the product of elements in a different column. The catch is that it needs to be every fifth element and has to be the first 52 elements from the index which we are at now. To explain it I need the product of column A with index 1,6,11,16 ... 262 to be under the first index in the new column. The next one will then be the product of indexes 2,7,12,17 ... 263 etc. Here's what I tried to code it as.

```
for i,r in df.iterrows():
     df["Rolling_Return"] = df.iloc[i:262+i:5,:].product
```

The issue is that my indexes are DateTime objects so this doesn't work. How should I change to code to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are DateTime objects, so you can reset your index :

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) # To insert index into 'index' column and create new index

for i,r in df.iterrows():
   df["Rolling_Return"] = df.iloc[i:262+i:5,:].product

df.set_index('index', inplace=True) # To set your dataframe index using 'index' column which is your old index
```